# How to redirect nginx location to different rule?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I'm using NGINX and trying to get all request that has subdirectory `FusionChart` goes to special place, my intention is all url with `[ROOT_URL]/FusionChart/` should go to `# Rule 3` below.
However, I have an existing nginx rules stated that all static content should go to `# Rule 2`.

**Nginx configuration:**

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
 access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;
 
# Rule 1
 location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/
 {
  root    /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;
  expires 30d;
 }
 
# Rule 2
 location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|jqGrid|images|common|ico|map|woff|woff2|ttf|html)$ {
   root /home/rcp/dev/public/others;
   expires 10y;
 }

 # Rule 3
 location ~ ^/(FusionCharts)/ {
                root /home/rcp/dev/public/charts;
                expires 10y;
 }

 location / {
  proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }
}
```

**The Tested URL:**

```
http://domain2.com/FusionCharts/index.html
```

This will fall to `# Rule 2`, how do I modify the rules so that the request above landed in `# Rule 3`?

Answer (score 0):

Regex matching locations are checked from first to last, the first found match is used for request processing. You can either swap second and third locations or use `location ^~ { ... }` syntax (check the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details):

```
location ^~ /FusionCharts/ {
    root /home/rcp/dev/public/charts/;
    expires 10y;
}
```

Please note that with above location `index.html` file for `/FusionCharts/index.html` request will be searched under `/home/rcp/dev/public/charts/FusionCharts` directory. If it isn't a desired behavior, use `alias /home/rcp/dev/public/charts/;` directive instead of `root` one.